# Create a column with a specific date

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to create a column with this date within my dataset (08/12/2020). So far I've tried this:

```
df$datemaster = 1
caseDay <- ymd("2020-12-08")
df$datemaster = ifelse(df$datemaster == '1', caseDay, "no")
```

but this is clearly not right.

Could anyone help me? - I'd just need a column full of "2020-12-08" in my dataset.

Thanks

Comment: did you try `df$datemaster <- ymd("2020-12-08")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Waldi suggested, the answer to this is:

df$datemaster <- ymd("2020-12-08")